# Why record_session command in Freeswitch capture only audio of one leg instead of entire call?

Tags: audio-streaming, recording, freeswitch

I'm using `record_session` command to record a call but when checking the saved record, I only hear audio from one leg, not all legs. Here's my config (follow from [official guide](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6587110)):

**== dial plan ==**

```
<extension name="simple test">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(1234)$">
      <action application="set" data="sound_prefix=$${sounds_dir}/en/us/callie"/>
      <!-- <action application="set" data="RECORD_STEREO_SWAP=true"/> -->
      <action application="set" data="RECORD_STEREO=true"/>
      <action application="record_session" data="/opt/calls/${strftime(%Y%m%d)}/record_${uuid}.mp3"/>
      <action application="answer" />
      <action application="sleep" data="5000" />
      <action application="playback" data="voicemail/vm-goodbye.wav" />
      <action application="sleep" data="15000" />
      <action application="hangup" />
    </condition>
</extension>
```

I made phone call from a soft-phone (Linphone) and there was no error log in Freeswitch console

- Without `RECORD_STEREO_SWAP=true`, the saved record contains only audio of `voicemail/vm-goodbye.wav` ([the FS log](https://pastebin.com/raw/zmr0eJ0W))
- With `RECORD_STEREO_SWAP=true` the saved record contains only audio of my speech ([the FS log](https://pastebin.com/raw/bwwRasB1))

What I want is that the saved record should contain both audio channels of voicemail and my speech.

Pls help me on this. Thank all of you!

Comment: add freeswitch log so I can help you to check.

Comment: Dear @HP371, I've updated the question with the FreeSwitch log (link to pastebin)... Thx you so much!

Comment: Try to remove both RECORD_STERO_SWAP and RECORD_STERO, and add <action application="set" data="media_bug_answer_req=true"/> and then try.

Comment: Wow, It's worked like a charm... but could you help to clarify further? (I also have to remove `<variable name="record_stereo" value="true"/>` within `directory/default.xml` file

Comment: not getting you, can you explain more what you want?

Comment: Could you explain or point out documents why it work without `record_stereo` variable? From [FS document](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/RECORD_STEREO), I thought it was required to have both caller & callee's speech in recorded file.